# Changing image source in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to alternate an image every click from 1st to 2nd and from 2nd to 1st(indefinitely). I tried this:

```js
function change() {

    var imgId = document.getElementById("image");

    var ubuntu = imgId.src="ubuntu.jpg";

    var debian = imgId.src="debian.jpg"

    if(imgId.src="ubuntu.jpg") {

        return debian;

    } else if(debian) {

        return ubuntu;
  
    }

}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="ubuntu.jpg" width="160" height="120" onclick = "change()">
```

Also, I would like to know the reason why the code is changing the image from ubuntu to debian but not from debian to ubuntu.

Comment: The comparison operator is either `==` or `===`. You're using `=` (assignment) which is messing up the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just toggle the `src` between your 2 images like so:

```
function change () {
    var imgElement = document.getElementById("image");

    if (imgElement.src === 'debian.jpg') {
        imgElement.src = 'ubuntu.jpg';
    }
    else {
        imgElement.src = 'debian.jpg';
    }
}
```

Or, using a [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx):

```
function change () {
    var imgElement = document.getElementById("image");
    var src = imgElement.src;

    imgElement.src = src === 'debian.jpg' ? 'ubuntu.jpg' : 'debian.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Each of them are turning only ubuntu to debian and then stopping on debian, as my code was doing so

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: on here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_image

Comment: So, how are you calling the `change` function?  It will toggle the image every time it is called - if you only call it once, it will only change the image once.

Comment: Okay, inline handlers like that are always a bad idea.  Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hg25ex5k/)

Comment: Thank you for helping and proving the code. It seems there's something wrong with the editor I was using.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could interchange between images is like this:

```
image = document.getElementById('image');

var toggle = 1;
function change() {
  if (toggle == 1) {
    image.src = "debian.jpg";
    toggle = 2;
  }
  if (toggle == 2) {
    image.src = "ubuntu.jpg";
    toggle = 1;
  }
}
```

And then set the image to have an onclick like you did:

```
<img id="image" src="ubuntu.jpg" onclick="change()">
```